# Data for specific id is not shown in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am beginner in Laravel. I want to try to view my data when click on update button, however it is not shown on the page. But, it did retrieve the id in the url route.

I have two folder. The member-list in the **admin** folder.

As you can see when I click the list edit button , it will retrieve the id in the url
[image]

and it shows the id the in the url. however, supposedly, it should show the row of the id.
[image]

like this one (I screenshot from someone's video)

[image]

So, this is my code.

MemberController

```
  function showData($id)
    {
        return Member::find($id);
    }
```

web.php

```
 Route::get('edit/{id}',  [MemberController::class,'showData']);
```

member-list.blade.php

```
 @foreach ($data2 as $item)
      <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td>{{$item->name}}</td>
               <td>{{$item->noPhone}}</td>
               <td>{{$item->noAhli}}</td>
               <td>{{$item->ic}}</td>
                <td>{{$item->age}}</td>
                <td>
                   <a href={{"edit/".$item->id}}>Edit</a>
              
                 </td>
              </tr>             
       </tbody>
@endforeach
```

What did I do wrong in my code?

Comment: when you run `php artisan route:list` is this route listed in the list?

Comment: nope. route edit is not listed.

Comment: make sure your routes are not cached (as route caching is completely not needed in local development) `php artisan route:clear` ... then run `php artisan route:list` to see if it shows up now

Comment: thank you sir, it shows up now

Comment: np, glad its working now

Answer (score 1):

Your routes are cached. Run `php artisan route:clear` to clear the route cache and all routes should show up in your route list: `php artisan route:list`.

While developing locally you don't need to cache your routes or configuration. It will only give you extra steps to do every time you change a configuration value or add/remove/adjust a route as you would have to re-cache the configuration or routes for every change.

There is no need to run `php artisan route:cache` or `php artisan config:cache` while developing locally; save those for the server. If you are going to run those commands make sure you remember that you did.